# Ibm watson pdf document is damanged from translation API

Tags: ibm-watson

I constantly get pdf erros when I run translation API.

I have success in submitting a document to translate API endpoint. When I try to download the translated document, it also works. But when I try to view the pdf file, it does not work. I have tried opening it on 4-5 different pdf viewers but to no avail.

Everything was working fine today 2 hours ago but now I get errors.

I use these APIs and test them on a simple sample  document

```
curl -X POST \
--user "apikey:{apikey}" \
--form "file=@sample.pdf" \
--form "source=en" \
--form "target=fr" \
https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/documents?version=2018-05-01
```

and the document download endpoint is as follows:

```
curl -X GET \
--user "apikey:{apikey}" \
--output "curriculum-fr.pdf" \
https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/documents/75a0b3b9-f123-43cf-937f-9899871b62f3/translated_document?version=2018-05-01
```

The downloaded pdf is always corrupted.

it was working perfectly fine 4 hours ago.

e.g. just a simple file like this: https://res.cloudinary.com/palsplate/image/upload/v1573769184/sample_rjlxrk.pdf

Comment: better contact with IBM support if you can’t find the solution here. I have no idea about your problem but got help for Watson’s NLP tool before.

Comment: Hard to help without knowing: difference between older and newer pdf, any error logs etc. But it seems contacting support might be the best